# Can Service Workers prioritize network access (i.e. QoS)?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I created a JS library that generates PNG thumbnails of videos at a given URL; all in the browser. It works great *except* sometimes it needs to get 10MB+ of data to generate the thumbnail. Consequently this can end up blocking any other client-side requests to that origin.

Is there a way to prioritize 'navigation' requests over the thumbnail/video requests using Service Workers and/or streams?

I'd like to make a request for a document I want to navigate to in my SPA, from the same origin as 2+ large video GET requests happening for the thumbnailing, and the navigation request would still happen with the thumbnailing GET requests only continuing once the navigation request completes? Basically a very simple form of QoS (Quality of Service).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. The service workers probably could throttle the download by intercepting the stream, but that's about it. The limit on concurrent requests per origin is surely enforced below that layer. You'd need to change the browser settings to circumvent that.

However, to allow navigation, you could try splitting your large downloads into multiple small chunks, then intermittently pause and resume the downloads leading to a larger number of smaller requests, not blocking that origin. Resumption of downloads is possible with [HTTP range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) - but only if the server supports it.
I guess a service worker could even do this transparently. However, the proper solution really would be using multiple domains (like a CDN does) or fixing the browser implementation.